# Differentiation under the integral sign in a triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $F(a,b,c) = \iiint\limits_{V}f(x,y,z,a,b,c) dx\ dy\ dz$,

V = $\{(x,y,z)| \ ... \}$ a connected, bounded and closed domain in $R^3$,

and $B((0,0,0),r))$ a ball in $R^3$ as a domain for $(a,b,c)$.

Under the assumption that $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ for instance are continuous for $(x,y,z) \in V$ and $(a,b,c) \in B$

is it possible to claim that:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}F(a,b,c) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \iiint\limits_{V}f(x,y,z,a,b,c) dx\ dy\ dz = \iiint\limits_{V} \frac{\partial}{\partial a}f(x,y,z,a,b,c) dx\ dy\ dz  $ ?

Comment: It's clearly false as the leftmost term is identically zero and the rightmost is not. Maybe you meant $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}F(a,b,c)$

Comment: no, F depends on $(x,y,z)$, the function F defines integrating on x,y,z in a specific point (a,b,c). you can refer to $\nabla F$  as $\nabla$ of the whole rigt side expression.

Comment: anyway, I edited the question to be more general and clear :)

Comment: It is still has the same problems, the leftmost expression is zero as $F$ is constant and the rightmost is not.

Comment: ok you are right I got it now, I'll try to give it a fix hopefully for the last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $f$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ are continuous as "a function of $6$ variables" $(x,y,z,a,b,c) \in V \times B$, then yes, the result is true, and the proof is pretty easy; it uses the fact that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous. Below, I present a statement which is valid in higher dimensions. You could probably get away with weaker hypotheses, but the version I'm stating is valid for many applications (at least the ones I've come across), and it is pretty easy to prove; the key ingredients are the (single-variable) mean-value theorem (for derivatives) and the fact that continuous fucntions on compact sets are uniformly continuous.

> **Theorem:** Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^m} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $V \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a compact Jordan-measurable set. Now, define the function $F:\mathbb{R^m} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
>   \begin{equation}
> F(\eta) = \int_V f(\xi, \eta) \, d^n \xi
> \end{equation}
>   (here $d^n \xi$ means $d \xi_1 \cdots d \xi_n$). If $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \eta_i} : \mathbb{R^n}\times \mathbb{R^m} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous ($1 \leq i \leq m$), then, for every $\eta \in \mathbb{R^m}$, we have that
>   \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \eta_i}(\eta) = \int_V \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \eta_i}(\xi, \eta) \, d^n \xi.
> \end{equation}

A few points to note are the following:

- if you don't know/understand what Jordan-measurable means, don't worry about it; it's just a condition to ensure the set $V$ is nice enough so that the integrals appearing actually exist. For example, if $n = 3$, then $V$ being a cube/ellipsoid/pumpkin are all examples of compact Jordan-measurable sets
- Of course, there is no need to have the domain of $f$ be all of $\mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^m}$. I simply didn't bother with smaller domains to make the statement more readable.
- By writing $\xi = (x,y,z)$ and $\eta = (a,b,c)$ hopefully you can see how to recover the special case you mentioned

Comment: Well It's true that I don't understand how to prove your more general case or how to prove my assumption,  but I do see how it applies on my case and it helps a lot to know that what I thought was correct, so thank you very much